# SharePoint/CSS3 Gradients/IE9

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

Okay, So I've got an internship and the office I work in uses SharePoint for everything and due to an OP firewall cannot/will not allow other programs to be used on their machine.

My supervisor would like to use gradients in SharePoint and allow them to appear in IE9. SharePoint doesn't seem to accept the filter protocol and because of the fire wall things like CSS3 pie and other gradient generators cannot be used.

I am editing on the HTML page in a web snippet; As you can probably surmise, SharePoint is new to me. Does anyone have any idea how to make gradients work in SharePoint so that they will register in IE9? I have seen a slew of the same answers and hoping for something new.

My apologies in advance if this is the wrong topic to post in, but I do believe its all connected.

Thank You

Ashley

Answer (score 1):

CSS gradients are simply not supported in IE9. You could try to implement them via svg based background-images, though. If you are using SCSS in conjunction with compass this also can be automated.